# How validate decimal with optional percentage symbol using Regex?

Tags: regex, windows, vb.net, visual-studio, decimal

As the title of the question, I need to validate regex using the following values​​:
 (Maximum 2 decimal places, and 9 integers) with an optional percent symbol.

Valid:

```
10%
 0%
 1111111.12%
 15.2%
 10
 2.3
```

Invalid:

```
 .%
 12.%
 .02%
 %
 123456789123.123
```

I tryed:

```
^[0-9]{0,9}([\.][0-9]{0,2})\d[\%]{0,1}?$
```

But It does not work as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
^\d{1,9}(\.\d{1,2})?%?$
```

I tested over rubular and it is ok for your set of example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]{1,9}([\.][0-9]{1,2})?[\%]?$
```